# jquery $.post() populates mysql table successfully, but $_POST array is always empty

Tags: php, jquery, .post

I have this oversimplified jquery post method:

```
  $('#del_prof').click(function() {
  var sss = 12345;
  $.post('logg3.php', { name: sss }); 
  });
```

and the php:

```
  $value = ($_POST['name']);
  run_q("INSERT INTO `temp` (info) VALUES ($value)");
```

**The problem is:**

It populates the mysql table successfully, but the `$_POST` array is always empty, regardless of what I try to echo or to var_dump.

How is this possible and why?

Comment: <<It populates the mysql table successfully>> so $_POST is not empty

Comment: exactly, what do you get when you `var_dump` the `POST` array?

Comment: this happens to me too @A.Wolff - i get Array() when doing the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Change `$.post('logg3.php', { name: sss });` to

`$.post('logg3.php', { data: { name: sss } });`

Comment: That doesn't seem correct. Here's the example from jQuery docs. `$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );`. Doesn't need the `data:`.